# Android simple calculator crash

Tags: java, android

I am new to android developing and made a simple calculator project. However, my app keeps crashing and I have no idea why

**Java Codes:**

```
package com.example.zhiwen.calculator;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button plus,minus,times,divide;
TextView textview3;
EditText first, second;
double no1 = 0, no2 = 0;
double answer = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plus);
    minus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.minus);
    times = (Button) findViewById(R.id.times);
    divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divide);
    textview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview3);
    first = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    second = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
}

public void ClickMeButton(View view){
    no1 = Integer.parseInt(first.toString());
    no2 = Integer.parseInt(second.toString());
    answer = no1 + no2;
    textview3.setText("Answer: " + answer);
}
public void ClickMeButton2(View view) {
    no1 = Integer.parseInt(first.toString());
    no2 = Integer.parseInt(second.toString());
    answer = no1 - no2;
    textview3.setText("Answer: " + answer);
}
public void ClickMeButton3(View view) {
    no1 = Integer.parseInt(first.toString());
    no2 = Integer.parseInt(second.toString());
    answer = no1 * no2;
    textview3.setText("Answer: " + answer);
}
public void ClickMeButton4(View view) {
    no1 = Integer.parseInt(first.toString());
    no2 = Integer.parseInt(second.toString());
    answer = no1 / no2;
    textview3.setText("Answer: " + answer);
}}
```

**Stack Trace:**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.zhiwen.calculator, PID: 2027
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for
> android:onClick
> at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6207)
> at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11094)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23639)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6207) 
> at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11094) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23639) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358) 
> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
> "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{271441f VFED..CL.
> ........ 0,57-441,193 #7f0b0063 app:id/editText}"
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:556)
> at
> com.example.zhiwen.calculator.MainActivity.ClickMeButton(MainActivity.java:33)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6207) 
> at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11094) 
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23639) 
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)

Comment: Look at the stack trace to determine the cause of the crash. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173

Comment: I have added in the stack trace. Could you explain to me the reason for the crash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to change

```
no1 = Integer.parseInt(first.toString());
```

to

```
no1 = Integer.parseInt(first.getText ().toString());
```

same for `second`

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the value from editText in wrong way
    `no1 = Integer.parseInt(first.toString());
    no2 = Integer.parseInt(second.toString());
    answer = no1 + no2;
    textview3.setText("Answer: " + answer);`

it should be `first.getText().toString();`